# Glassfish deployment exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I'm developing a JavaEE application on Glasfish Application Server. I'm developing so I'm continously deployig/undeploying the application.

Everything worked great until a few hours ago when I got this error while deploying:

```
GRAVE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare    method
GRAVE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method
GRAVE: Exception while preparing the app
GRAVE: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-unit-ref-name [persistence/decreg-entite] in scope of the module called [declaration-reglementaire-ear#declaration-reglementaire-serviceweb-0.0.3-RELEASE.war]. Please verify your application.
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-unit-ref-name [persistence/decreg-entite] in scope of the module called [declaration-reglementaire-ear#declaration-reglementaire-serviceweb-0.0.3-RELEASE.war]. Please verify your application.
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears, the persistence unit named 'decreg-entite' is mentioned in your domain.xml file but the jpa configuration file, persistence.xml doesn't define all about the persistence unit.